# Codeigniter - synchronising mysql tables to a different database on a different sever

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I have two databases on different servers which I need to keep in sync. The two databases are defined in my database config and I am setting up connections as such:

```
$DB1 = $this->load->database('master', TRUE);
$DB2 = $this->load->database('live', TRUE);
```

How can I get the entire contents of the 'products' table on $DB1 and synchronise it on $DB2 - I could just truncate the table on $DB2 and write the full data (inelegant and could cause issues on live site) or can I use codeigniter to properly syncronise the 2nd table; adding, updating and deleting records on a record by record by record basis?

I had tried:

```
$products = $DB1->from('products')->get()->result_array();

$count = count($products);

for($i = 0 ; $i < $count; $i++)
{
     $q = $DB2->from('products')->where('id', $products[$i]['id'])->get();

     if($q->num_rows() > 0)
     {
           [Update the data]
     } 
     else
     {
           [Insert the data]
     }
}
```

But this method does not take into account records which exist on the $DB2 which have been deleted from $DB1? I prefer this method of updating products but cannot have widowed products on the live site.

Comment: Why not set up a mysql replication? If you have access to the config files. This solves all your issues much better.

Comment: Unfortunately the full system includes users working on the live database as well as admins working on the master - the daily data will be synced to the master once a day, changes will then be input at the master and then re-synced back the other way.

Comment: Have you taken a look at Master-Master-Replications?

Comment: That's perfect! Please post as an answer so I can accept it =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issues would all be solved with replication feature of MySQL.

Since both your databases should be writeable and all changes should be replicated to the respectively other server, you might want to set up a master-master replication. You can find tutorials on this topic on the internet, for example [this one](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-mysql-master-master-replication).

Please keep in mind that this is not an easy solution. Being able to write to two databases, which need to sync, might result in conflicts (which you would also have in a script based solution). You might want to take steps to make sure that both databases cannot diverge too much from each other, if they loose their connection between them. You might also want to set `auto_increment_increment` and `auto_increment_offset` ([see the manual on this topic](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-master.html)) to circumvent possible duplicates in autoincrement columns.

If you use the autoincrement settings above, please note that this also "changes" semantics of the autoincrement column. Until now you had a column, which you could `ORDER BY` your result set to get your result set ordered in insertion time order. This will not work if you specify different offsets. One server might insert row with id=1 later than the other server inserts row with id=6. All queries of the form `ORDER BY id` need to be changed to e.g. `ORDER BY insertion_date` (with `insertion_date` being a column which contains the timestamp of insertion time of that row).